# i am not able to install Laravel. some bug with composer

Tags: php, laravel, shell, terminal, composer-php

I am using composer to install `laravel`. Everything was working fine. but suddenly now,  when I am trying to install new `laravel` app using composer. I am getting following error. Till yesterday it was working well.
Please check error screenshot here: 
 https://prnt.sc/in1r9v

I can not understand why this is happening.

I also tried to do `composer self-update` i got following error:-

https://prnt.sc/in1sti

Well, I have found the solution for this: 
This happened to me because of ISP routing error.
To solve this you have to do following steps
Step 1: Get the name of your network device(terminal):

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Step 2: Disable IPv6 on that device (in this case "Wi-Fi"):

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

Step 3: Run composer ...

You can enable IPv6 again with:

```
networksetup -setv6automatic Wi-Fi
```

That said, if this fixes your problem, please talk to your ISP about it to try and resolve the routing errors. That's the best way to get things resolved for everyone.

FOR REF. CHECK:  https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode

Comment: Could be a temporary connection problem. Try again https://packagist.org/packages.json seems reachable.

Comment: @kerbholz just now tried. The same error.

Comment: @RakeshKohali copy paste this in browser and see what happens https://getcomposer.org/download/1.6.3/composer.phar.sig

Comment: @JagadeshaNH it is giving following result:  https://prnt.sc/in20gu

Comment: Can you now try now sudo composer self-update

Comment: still same error

Comment: anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @RakeshKohali is your issue fixed? if so, do share your solution.

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look. I have found the solution for my bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution for this: 
This happened to me because of ISP routing error.
To solve this you have to do following steps.
(THIS IS FOR MAC USERS)

Step 1: Get the name of your network device(terminal):

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Step 2: Disable IPv6 on that device (in this case "Wi-Fi"):

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

Step 3: Run composer ...

You can enable IPv6 again with:

```
networksetup -setv6automatic Wi-Fi
```

That said, if this fixes your problem, please talk to your ISP about it to try and resolve the routing errors. That's the best way to get things resolved for everyone.

FOR REFERENCE CHECK: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode

Comment: LOL. Never expected that to be a network protocol level issue.

Answer (score 2):

This could possibly be because of missing necessary SSL certificates on your system.

On Ubuntu, run this command `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates` and use composer.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect this is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the ans . It didn't help (

Answer (score 0):

Did your internet is working fine? Please check again it may be a temporary connectivity issue. I just run composer self-update and its working fine.